# filtering facebook friends by age

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say I have an authenticated facebook user and I want to present a list of their friends that only includes friends who are ages 21+.. is this possible with any of the APIs out there? I don't need the exact age of the user, just if they are over 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is ask for the scope/permission that lets you see friends birthdays and filter out anyone who doesn't have a public birthday. This is how we did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this unless facebook opens everybody's account and allow you to watch all their details, including age.

Comment: This is what I figured... I was hoping there was some provision for age tiers.. 13+ 18+ 21+, etc... this would make life much easier for dealing with "adult" content like liquor promos and such...